# Is super.onCreateContextMenu() required?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have an `ActionBarActivity`( from v7 support library) which loads a `fragment`( from the v4 support library). I implemented `onCreateContextMenu()` in the fragment as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

In my attempt to understand if a call to the super method was actually required, I dug through following the android source code:

1. [Fragment](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#1313), which has one line of code:

   ```
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
       getActivity().onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
   }
   ```
2. [ActionBarActivity](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.java), which does not have `onCreateContextMenu()`.
3. As `ActionBarActivity` is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`, I looked at [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java), which also does not have `onCreateContextMenu()`.
4. As `FragmentActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`, I looked at [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#2897). Its method is empty:

   ```
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
   }
   ```

I concluded that there is no point in calling the super method. Yet, the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) does call super. So is my conclusion wrong? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is right, the documentation just has a superflous line of code there, that does no harm.

Other methods like `onCreate()`, `onResume()` etc.however, **do require** a call to the method in the parent class and throw runtime exceptions if they are not called.

Comment: I am relieved to hear that you agree. But i am still curious as to why they would add that line if it does nothing. I wonder if there is some explanation for it somewhere.

Comment: The documentation is only made by humans. There are tons of documentation so not every line is always 100% perfect.

Comment: Another explanation: When you create an overridden method in a class using Eclipse's auto-complete method, it automatically adds a super.methodName() call. Perhaps the author of the example also was not sure if that call is needed or not and left it in there.

Comment: Hmmm..but eclipse's auto complete does not fill out onCreateContextMenu(). I'll settle for your human error theory.